# Flux of a vector field through a tetrahedron

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, vector-analysis

Given the vector field:

$F = \langle z, y, zx \rangle$ and the tetrahedron enclosed by the coordinate planes and the plane

$\frac{x}{4}+\frac{y}{2}+\frac{z}{5}=1 \iff z = 5-\frac{5x}{4}-\frac{5y}{2}$

We want the flux through the surface of this tetrahedron.

We thus know that, by the divergence theorem:

$\int\int_SF\cdot ds = \int\int\int_Vdiv(F)dV$

We can choose our bounds as:

$0\leq x\leq4;$

$0\leq y \leq 5-\frac{5x}{4};$

$0\leq z \leq 5 - \frac{5x}{4}-\frac{5y}{2}$

And we know:

$div(F) = 0+1+x =1+x$

Thus we get the integral:

$\int^{4}_0\int^{5-\frac{5x}{4}}_0\int^{5-\frac{5x}{4}-\frac{5y}{2}}_0 (1+x)dzdydx = -50/3$

This is in fact incorrect, but I do not know why nor what the right answer is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your bounds for $y$ are incorrect. The intersection of the plane and the $xy$-plane occurs when $z = 0$: $$\frac{x}{4} + \frac{y}{2} = 1 \iff y = 2 - \frac{x}{2}$$

So your bounds for $y$ should be $0 \leq y \leq 2 - \frac{x}{2}$.